# How to sort alphanumeric characters in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sorting, alphanumeric

I've alphanumeric values present in MySQL DB Column; let's say TOPIC. Its values are as follows:

```
P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7, P8, P9 , P10, P11, P12, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, C8, C9, C10, C11, C12, C13 and so on...
```

When sort is applied on TOPIC; it gives order as  `C1,C10,....` 
I'm looking for sort order as, `C1, C2, C3, .... C13... P1, P2, ..... P13`

Is there any MySQL function to achieve same?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
ORDER BY LEFT(TOPIC,1), RIGHT(TOPIC,2)
```

Comment: Wouldn't come `10` before `P9` in that?

Answer (score 1):

First sort on the first character, then on the rest of the characters, as int:

```
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(topic, 1, 1), CAST(SUBSTRING(topic, 2) AS UNSIGNED)
```

Haven't tried it out.